# Code meaning in Haskell 99 problems

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, fold

I have been working on the 99 Haskell problems challenge and one of the solutions of problem no. 3 - Get the k-th element of a list, counting from 1, not 0 - is:

```
elementAt''' xs n = head $ foldr ($) xs $ replicate (n - 1) tail
```

I understand that, given a list, we could perform (n - 1) `tail` operations and the first element of the final list is the one we are looking for. As it is written, the `foldr`'s accumulator's initial value is the given list, but I fail to identify the second argument, which should be a list, right?

I would appreciate if you explained the first steps `foldr` makes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list argument is `replicate (n - 1) tail`, which is a list that contains the function `tail` `(n-1)` times. So we have `($)` as the function, `xs` as the initial element and `[tail, tail, ..., tail]` as the list. So the result of the fold is `tail $ tail $ ... $ tail $ xs`.